# Project cannot run anymore [Visual Studio]

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, binary

I have a project that is not running anymore. I keep getting an error dialog that says "This application cannot be started. Do you want to view more information about this issue?". Also in the console, it says "The program '[10068] BinaryConverter.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0)." Someone told me to uncheck the "Prefer 32-bit" option. When I do that, although the error dialog box is gone, the console still displays The program '[10068] BinaryConverter.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0)." I cannot open the wpf app.

EDIT: By the way, the release folder is empty. When the app was working, my release folder had some things in it.

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public void readstuff (){

    }

    public static string getBetween(string strSource, string strStart, string strEnd)
    {
        int Start, End;
        if (strSource.Contains(strStart) && strSource.Contains(strEnd))
        {
            Start = strSource.IndexOf(strStart, 0) + strStart.Length;
            End = strSource.IndexOf(strEnd, Start);
            return strSource.Substring(Start, End - Start);
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    private void BrowseButton2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        OpenFileDialog fd = new OpenFileDialog();
        fd.InitialDirectory = "\\\\folder1\\savelocation";
        fd.Filter = "Binary Files  | *.bin";
        fd.ShowDialog();
        filePath2.Text = fd.FileName;
    }
    private void SavingPathButton2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FolderSelectDialog fs = new FolderSelectDialog();
        fs.InitialDirectory = "\\\\Nx3200\\supplier\\FONEX\\LambdaGain";
        fs.ShowDialog();
        savingPath2.Text = fs.FileName;
    }
    private void StartConversion2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
        Byte [] a1 = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath2.Text);
        Byte[] a2 = new Byte[2 * (a1.Length)];

        int i = 0;
        while(i < a1.Length) {
            a2[2*i] = a1[i];
            a2[(2 * i) + 1] = 0;
                i++;
        }
            try
            {

                string fullPath = Path.Combine(savingPath2.Text, "new");
             File.WriteAllBytes(savingPath2.Text, a2);
             MessageBox.Show("Conversion Complete");
            } catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
            {
                Form3 frm3 = new Form3();
                frm3.Text = "X-Formatter";
                frm3.ShowDialog();
            }

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            string stackTrace = ex.ToString();
            Form1 frm1 = new Form1(stackTrace);
            frm1.Text = "X-Formatter";
            frm1.ShowDialog();
        }
    }

    private void BrowseButton1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog fd = new OpenFileDialog();
        fd.InitialDirectory = "\\\\folder1\\savelocation";
        fd.Filter = "Binary Files  | *.bin";
        fd.ShowDialog();
        filePath1.Text = fd.FileName;
    }

    private void SavingPathButton1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FolderSelectDialog fs = new FolderSelectDialog();
        fs.InitialDirectory = "\\\\folder1\\savelocation";
        fs.ShowDialog();
        savingPath1.Text = fs.FileName;
    }

    private void StartConversion1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            Byte[] a1 = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath1.Text);
            Byte[] a2 = new Byte[(a1.Length) / 2];


            a2[0] = a1[0];
            int i = 2;
            int j = 1;
            while (i < a1.Length)
            {

                a2[j] = a1[i];
                i = i + 2;
                j += 1;
            }
            try
            {
                File.WriteAllBytes(savingPath1.Text, a2);
                MessageBox.Show("Conversion Complete");
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
            {
                Form3 frm3 = new Form3();
                frm3.Text = "XGIGA formatter";
                frm3.ShowDialog();
            }
        } catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            string stackTrace = ex.ToString();
            Form1 frm1 = new Form1(stackTrace);
            frm1.Text = "XGIGA Formatter";
            frm1.ShowDialog();
        }
    }

    private void FilePath1_TextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AboutBox1 ab = new AboutBox1();
        ab.Text = "XGIGA Formatter";
        ab.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe instead of posting all your source code here, try to narrow it down first?  And what is BinaryConverter.exe?? it is clearly responsible for crashing

Comment: It is basically an app that converts a binary file into another binary file. The new binary file has a 00x0 (hex) after every hex number. I would've narrowed it but I gave the full source code because I do not know where the problem is

Comment: please configure VS to stop on all exceptions (Exception Settings \ Common language runtime exception check box must be checked) and try to run your application using the VisualStudio

Comment: @oleksa still the same thing

Comment: it looks to me like a misconfiguration thing. but with almost no information in your post it's hard to tell. I would compare the csproj with the working version first, then look at solution settings like arch and build order and so on

Comment: are you running the application from the VisualStudio debugger? You can open the solution in the VisualStidio and hit F10 key (`Debug\Step over` command) and check when your application fails.

Comment: Yes I am running in debugger and by doing F10 it still fails

Comment: Microsoft has a troubleshooting page for this error message. Try some of the suggestions from there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/application-not-started

Comment: so you have the same error but do you see any line from sources running under VS debugger? I mean does it start to run your source code or it fails before ? Can you create a new wpf solution (from VS template) and check will it start ?